# Magento2.3 - How to add grouped product in cart using REST API?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, grouped-products

Currently i am using Magento2.3.5. I checked documentation 2.3, there is no statement like grouped product in it.. So any one tell me how can we add grouped product in cart using magento rest api?

Answer (score 0):

It's documented down the bottom of the page :D
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/grouped-product/create-and-manage-grouped-products.html#add-a-grouped-product-to-a-cart

Comment: Your mentioned link has over all grouped product and its qtd.. But What i need is, How to add qtd for each item in grouped product? There is no documentation for that

Comment: Looks like the 2.3 api might not have supported an ability to set the quantity of each product in the group. [It is supported in 2.4.3](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.3-admin/tag/cartsmineitemsitemId#operation/quoteCartItemRepositoryV1SavePut) at least.